# Error while building Tensorflow using bazel

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I'm currently following the instructions [here](https://gist.github.com/kmhofmann/e368a2ebba05f807fa1a90b3bf9a1e03)
to build tensorflow from source using bazel.

After setting up the configuration, and attempting to build it, I get this error:

> Cuda Configuration Error: Error reading C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU
>   Computing To olkit/CUDA/v9.0/include/cudnn.h: java.io.IOException:
>   ERROR: src/main/native/win dows/processes-jni.cc(239):
>   CreateProcessW("grep" --color=never -A1 -E "#define CUDNN_MAJOR"
>   "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.0/include/cu
>   dnn.h"): Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.

The last phrase translates to "no such file or directory".

But I'm 100% sure I installed cuDNN 7.1.2 correctly, merging the downloaded bin/include/lib folder's with the preexisting CUDA folders. If I copy/paste the path from the error message, there it is cudnn.h! I also run everything in administator etc..

This problem shows up a few times on google, linking it to a mis-configured theano setup, but I'm not using theano right now. 
Why doesn't bazel find the file, when it's definitely there?

EDIT: I would also be very thankful if anyone has a link a pre-built version of tensorflow for CUDA compute capability 3.0!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: FYI: Windows build from source is not officially supported. I heart people having some luck using cmake - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake

Comment: Any changes on this?
I'm trying same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicated that grep.exe can't be found.  I tried grep for Windows and msys2.  Both will do.